# yii call user login function from another module

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.17 and have this [user module](https://github.com/nineinchnick/yii-usr) installed. I created another module called dashboard.

In the dashboard controller i have this function

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}
```

and the in the `index.php` view i want to display the login form of my `user module` which controller is `usr/default/login`. Basically i want the login form of the user module to work in `dashboard/default/index`.

i added this in my `index.php` but get a 404 error

```
<?php
     $myModule = Yii::app()->getModule('usr');

     Yii::app()->runController($myModule->id . '/default/login');
?>
```

Any idea how i can do this? Thanks

Comment: Would you try to set the path in config/main.php ?
    
//Modules Users for authentication
        'user' => array(
            # registration path
            'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),
            # recovery password path
            'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),
            # login form path
            'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
            # page after login
            //'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),
            # page after logout
            'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),
        ),